# Comparing already added datagrid values with new one

Tags: c#, .net

Hey guys so i am running into a small problem i am adding rows to my gridview from a textbox that reads from the database, the rows are being added successfully but i want to validate if same row was added so that the Quantity column increases by 1 so here is my code:

```
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select medicine_name,medicine_sellingPrice from Medicine where medicine_barcode = '" + txtBarcode.Text + "'", con);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader["medicine_name"].ToString(), reader["medicine_sellingPrice"].ToString(), z });

                          //Calculations
                          int sum = 0;
                          int sum1 = 0;
                          for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                          {
                              sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                              sum1 = sum * 1500;
                          }
                          toolDollar.Text = "Cost In Dollar: " + sum.ToString() + " " + "$";
                          toolLBP.Text = "Cost in LBP: " + sum1.ToString() + " " + "LBP";
                          toolCount.Text = "Total Items:  " + dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

each time i add same row i want my Z value to increase on the already added row and not add a new one.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just pointing out that your code is vulnerable to sql injection...

Comment: Why not perform the grouping in the query?

Comment: i know it's vulnerable it's not done yet, and how do i perform the grouping in the query?